# Routing from Page 1 to Page 2, then coming back to Page 1 using browser back, breaks Page 1 [NextJS 13]

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using `next` 13.4.5 and `/app` based routing with typescript.

In my page 1, I have `<Link>`(next/link), from which I navigate to Page 2.
If I use the browser back button to come back to page 1, the whole page breaks. For example, the top section vanishes, and page starts from middle. CSS for the rest of the pages don't work, etc.

My page 1 is fully SSR. But in page 2, I have used `"use client";` in the `page.tsx`.

Sharing a deployed version of the above mentioned site:

1. The [home page](https://buzzli.vercel.app) is the page 1.
2. The [login page](https://buzzli.vercel.app/login) is the page 2.

For reproduction, please go to https://buzzli.vercel.app and at the top right corner, press the "Get Started" button. This is the `next/link` tag. It will take you to the login page. Then try to come back to the previous page using the back button. You'll see the error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, so not sharing any code.

Comment: I didn't find any issue on your website its works completely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

Actually the problem lied in nested `<html>` tags.

The project structure was something like this:

```
/
--> layout
--> page
--> /login
    --> layout (the problem lied here)
    --> page
```

By mistake, I had put another `html` tag in this inner layout file.